# Howto add system-default selection designs to (gen)lists?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I have a nice genlist, and I want to add checkboxes (/toggles) to all items.

I checked these pages:

- https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/guides/ui/efl/wearable/component-genlist/
- https://developer.tizen.org/ko/design/wearable/ui-components/selection-controls?langredirect=1
- https://developer.tizen.org/ko/design/wearable/ui-components/list?langredirect=1

> You can provide an on/off switch, checkbox, or radio button along with the main text.

Perfect. How?

I'm aiming to be able to select items from the list, either with something like this:

[image]

Or with something like this:

[image]

I know I can use *item_styles*. Also know I can add my own images to `swallow.end` or similar.

**But is there a way to use the *same* designs as the OS uses? To *not break* UI consistency?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use elm_check on swallow.end part.
I do not know which style do you use,
so here is sample with style "1text.1icon.1"

```
Evas_Object* _gl_icon_get(void *data, Evas_Object *obj, const char *part)
{
        item_data *id = (item_data *)data;
        Evas_Object *content = NULL;

        if (strcmp(part, "elm.icon")) return NULL;

        id->check = content = elm_check_add(obj);
        elm_check_state_set(content, EINA_FALSE);
        elm_check_state_pointer_set(content, &id->checked);
        evas_object_show(content);

        return content;
}
```

if you want to check state changed when item clicked,
call this,

```
elm_check_state_set(id->check, !id->checked);
```

in item's selection callback.

you can see the full code in elm-demo-tizen-wearable/src/genlist.c
(https://review.tizen.org/gerrit/#/admin/projects/profile/wearable/platform/core/uifw/elm-demo-tizen-wearable, tizen 5.5 branch).
hope you now can access review.tizen.org.
or you can see the Alarm sample in tizen-studio.
but the look of checkbox will be different that you shared image,
I think it's because of version differences, Tizen SDK theme is outdated one..